# Is this question about a "hello world" off topic?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, scope, recommendation-questions

The following question is not asking someone to **find a tool** or **recommend a library**

> [How do I use SimplSockets with a delegate for a "hello world" project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25087508/328397)

It is **about & regarding** an off-site resource, but everything technically is an off site resource.

Can anyone clarify the reasoning to me?

Either way I answered my own question and my personal investment is nill in it; other than the outcome of this meta post.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I agree with you; I don’t think the current close votes are valid.

Indeed, there are two things that could have been interpreted as an off-site resource:

- **The ‘input’:** You’re using some external library. I don’t see this as a big deal; there’s plenty of nonstandard libraries being used, but I don’t see anyone calling a witch-hunt on [boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boost).
- **The ‘output’:** Some questions explicitly ask for recommendations on off-site resources, like libraries or tutorials. These *are* off-topic.

Your question here on Meta seems to focus a little on the input-side of it, but I think the people who have voted to close are objecting to the output-side. In particular, your original question was *very specific* about “looking for something”:

> ## Looking for a “Hello World” of SimplSocket() library
>
> I'm looking for a sample on how to configure and use SimplSocket, and found none. […] I'm hoping the sample will mention […]

If you really were looking for some sort of off-site resource as it appeared, it’s off-topic. But there is an easy way to get around this: rather than asking for some sort of resource, ask for whatever content you know might *appear* in such a resource. In your specific case of asking for a sample of how to do X, you might instead just ask how to do X. I tried to make that more explicit [in my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/25087508/3).

Now, that doesn’t necessarily mean you’re off home-free; in particular, you could still get bitten by the ‘too broad’ close reason if the resulting snippet is expected to be long enough.  But that’s a separate concern; rewording to ask how to do something rather than resources on how to do it gets you a little further.

Comment: Thank you for your very articulate and specific way of describing the problem and getting me to understand how I can improve.   Love the metaphor to IO

Answer (score 7):

I was one of the ones who originally voted to close.  It was a question nakedly asking for code and I have always been under the impression that such questions, without any demonstration of an effort to write the code themself, is off-topic.

For reference, here's the original version of the question:

---

> I'm looking for a sample on how to configure and use [SimplSocket][1], and found none.
>
> I checked:
>
> - [Stackoverflow][2]
> - [The author's blog][3]
> - [Git][4]  (no unit tests to get me there)
> - Google
> - Yes, even Bing.
>
> I'm hoping the sample will mention any need for `IDisposable`, or any quirks relevant in a multithreaded environment.  Also, how to correctly initialize it, send data, etc.
>
> ... anything to get my mind thinking "concurrently" on sockets would be helpful.

---

If the above question is actually *on-topic*, then that runs contrary to a vast array of other questions that the community closes with extreme regularity.

That being said, the question as written now is a lot better and I suspect I would not have closed it as it stands.  Though it still seems borderline to me.

Comment: To me it's also still *too broad*.

Comment: To me, lots of stackoverflow questions are voted off topic by those with lots of "reputation" I think they get in a hurry looking for more points

Comment: @stuck huh? you don't earn rep for closing questions.